# Reinstalling yum conflicts with previous version but yum is not available

Tags: yum

I am reinstalling yum using:

```
sudo rpm -ivh yum-3.4.3-158.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
```

And I get a lot of conflicts of this type:

```
file /usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py from install of yum-3.4.3-158.el7.centos.noarch conflicts with file from package yum-3.4.3-154.el7.centos.noarch
```

I understand that yum must have been installed earlier using `yum-3.4.3-154.el7.centos.noarch` package, but my system doesn't have any yum.

When I type yum in the shell it doesn't find it. This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/458692/123892). I understand that yum is missing from the system, but how should I install it now?

**EDIT:**

I tried `sudo rpm -Uvh yum-3.4.3-158.el7.centos.noarch.rpm` and typed `yum` i the shell. It is not installed :

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 27 2018, 17:29:31)
[GCC 7.2.0]
```

Comment: Tried doing that... It leads to a new problem when I use yum now.

Comment: "It is not installed" is incorrect.  If it were not installed you would be seeing `yum: command not found`.  It is lacking its requisites - in this case, seemingly a Python module.

Comment: You can "always" remove the rpm using "rpm -e yum" (perhaps someone removed the files without doing that).

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error:

> Performing yum update results in the error "No module named yum"

It's typically a Python problem with a module that YUM requires/needs. To resolve this:

```
$ sudo -Es
$ unset PYTHONHOME
```

Then re-install python:

```
$ rpm -Uvh --replacefiles --replacepkgs python-<version>.rpm
```

This entire topic is covered on access.redhat.com's article titled: [Why yum fails on system with "No module named yum" error ?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21199).

> Root causes
>
> - `PYTHONHOME` variable was set as environment variable on system.
> - Python libraries/files are modified which can be observed from output of `rpm -Va` command.
> - Third party python modules are installed on system which found in output of "ldd /usr/bin/python" command.
> - The package rpm-python* is not installed.